# Grails 2.3.2/.3 Upgrade - unable to map URLs ending in .html

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

After upgrading a grails app from version 2.2.2 to 2.3.2 and eventually 2.3.3, I noticed that some links that are previously working, now returns a 404 status.

To illustrate, here are the sample links and the corresponding URL mapping entry that was originally working in v2.2.2:

```
http://localhost:7080/pages/mytestpage
http://localhost:7080/pages/mytestpage.html
```

***UrlMappings.groovy***

```
static mappings = {
    "pages/mytestpage"(controller: 'testController', action: 'testAction')
}
```

After upgrade, among the given links, the link below does not work anymore (i.e. the link with .html):

```
http://localhost:7080/pages/mytestpage.html
```

One way to fix this issue is by changing the URLMappings entry to as below:

***UrlMappings.groovy (MODIFIED)***

```
static mappings = {
    "pages/mytestpage(.$format)?"(controller: 'testController', action: 'testAction')
}
```

My question is, is there a way to resolve this problem without having to update the URLMappings entry? Anybody who can explain how such mapping actually worked in version 2.2.2 will also be a great help. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Using **(.html)?** instead of **(.$format)?** in UrlMappings.groovy works as well and was actually used.

Also, in this example the app server is being hit directly and web server is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Grails 2.2.x, the `grails.mime.file.extensions = true` setting along with the `grails.mime.types` controlled the extension in the URL. Basically, Grails ignored the extensions that are listed in the mime type and mapped the url to the controller accordingly.(thats why mytestpage.html works and not mytestpage.exe nor mytestpage.anything)

It appears that the above behavior was change in Grails 2.3.x+ to support the REST improvements. Even the default mappings in `URLMappings.groovy` have changed accrodingly

```
//Grails 2.2.x
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

to

```
//Grails 2.3.x
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

Your solution seems to be the correct way to fix the issue

Comment: Your answer helped me better understand this concept. Thanks.